# Pass datagridview values to message box with formatting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to pass data from one formatted column in datagridview to message box but the problem is that the data is passed but the formatting is not included. I mean the column that I want to display is a numeric column when I pass the data, only the numbers is being passed. I want the comma and the period to be included.

Here is the image:

[image: Here is the column]

And here is the message box result:

[image: Message box result]

As you can see there is no comma and period. I want to include the comma and period.

Here is the `datagridview_cellformatting`:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 7) Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType = GetType(Double)
        DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value = "0.00"
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the `MessageBox`:

```
MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Try using string formatting for numeric values: `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:N2}", DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value))` or explicitly set like `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value))`.

Comment: Side note:  that is not the proper way to handle the `CellFormatting` event.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the format for the column cells here:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

You need to provide that same format specifier when converting the value to a `String` anywhere else too, e.g.

```
MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value.ToString(DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format))
```

If you were to have `Option Strict On`, which you ALWAYS should, then you'd need to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value).ToString(DataGridView1.Columns(7).DefaultCellStyle.Format))
```